# When does a non-zero eigenvector exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $M$ is a square matrix such that $M^2 \neq 0$. Does this imply that $M$ has a non-zero eigenvalue?

Comment: No. If $M^{2}\neq 0$ but $M^{n} =0$ for some $n >2$ then also $0$ is the only eigen value.

Answer (score 2):

No. Take
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $x^3$, so all eigenvalues are zero, but $M^2 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix corresponding to a quarter turn rotation in the plane. It has no real eigenvalues. It does have two complex eigenvalues.